# How to convert a string to an array using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string

I have a text field that takes in a string value, like

```
"games,fun,sports"
```

My main goal here is to take the string and turn it into a Array like this:

```
[games, fun, sports]
```

in the filters attribute for the integrations object I have. Right now I have the beginning of a method that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

View:

```
  <%= form_for @integrations, url: url_for(:controller => :integrations, :action => :update, :id => @integrations.id) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :filters %>
   <%= f.text_field :filters, class: "filter-autocomplete" %>
   <%= f.submit "Save" %>
  <% end %>
```

That is the text field that takes in the string.

Model:

```
def filters=(filters)

end
```

This is the place that I'd like to make the switch from string to array.

Controller:

```
 def update
    @integrations = current_account.integrations.find(params[:id])

    if @integrations.update_attributes(update_params)
      flash[:success] = "Filters added"
      redirect_to account_integrations_path
    else
      render :filters
    end
  end

  def filters
    @integrations = current_account.integrations.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def update_params
    [:integration_webhook, :integration_pager_duty, :integration_slack].each do |model|
      return params.require(model).permit(:filters) if params.has_key?(model)
    end
  end
```

So, recap: I have a integrations model that takes in a string of filters. I want a method that will break up the string into an element of filter attributes.

Here is the object that I'm trying to add the filters to:

Object:

```
 id: "5729de33-befa-4f05-8033-b0acd5c4ee4b",
 user_id: nil,
 type: "Integration::Webhook",
 settings: {"hook_url"=>"https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/1062282/4b0h0daa/"},
 created_at: Mon, 29 Aug 2016 03:30:29 UTC +00:00,
 owner_id: "59d4357f-3210-4ddc-9cb9-3c758fc1ef3a",
 filters: "[\"Hey\", \"ohh\"]">
```

As you can see the `filters` is what I'm trying to modify. Instead of this in the object:

```
"[\"Hey\", \"ohh\"]"
```

I would like this:

```
[Hey, ohh]
```

Comment: `[games, fun, sports]` and `[Hey, ohh]` would be an illegal array definition unless `games`, `fun`, `sports`, `Hey` and `ohh` are variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not clear what you're after, but generally, when you have a string like:

```
"games,fun,sports"
```

you can use `split(',')` to break it on the commas and turn it into an array of strings:

```
"games,fun,sports".split(',') # => ["games", "fun", "sports"]
```

If you're receiving a JSON encoded array of strings, it'll look like:

```
'["games", "fun", "sports"]'
```

AKA:

```
'["games", "fun", "sports"]' # => "[\"games\", \"fun\", \"sports\"]"
```

which can be returned to a Ruby array of strings easily enough:

```
require 'json'

JSON['["games", "fun", "sports"]'] # => ["games", "fun", "sports"]
```

Comment: The Rails `to_json` method is pretty handy and always present.

Comment: @tadman `to_json` generates a string from an array, but it's intended to be the opposite

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use JSON.

```
require 'json'
filters = "[\"Hey\", \"ohh\"]"
JSON.parse(filters)
```

returns:

```
["Hey","ohh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove extra characters and then split the string into array using the split pattern like this:

```
"[\"Hey\", \"ohh\"]".gsub(/(\[\"|\"\])/, '').split('", "')
```

Which returns:

```
["Hey", "ohh"]
```